# native_modules.gradle file is deleting as soon as react-redux is installed

Tags: react-native, gradle, android-emulator, command-prompt

I have created an app in react native for my project. When I copy my projects file in the app folder then run the app it said that in node_module react-redux does not exist then I installed react-redux using `npm install react-redux@7.0.3` in my app folder after that when I run `run-android` command in command prompt for this project it is telling that -
`Could not read script 'E:\AppFolder\MyApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.` .

After that, I wiped the data of emulator and run `run-android`, but it is still giving me the same error and app is not installing in the emulator.

Here is the error which command prompt is displaying :

````
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && gradlew.bat app:installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file 'E:\AppFolder\MyApp\android\settings.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings 'TribeBond'.
> Could not read script 'E:\AppFolder\MyApp\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' as it does not exist.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 10s
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.```
````

Comment: Are you using a monorepo?

Comment: @Tasso Evangelista, Please can you tell me how do I know that I am using Monorepo?...actually I am new in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I follow these steps to solve my problem-

1. I build a new app and run it using `react-native run-android` command.
2. Then I installed all dependencies one by one, which is going to use in the app.
3. Then run `npm install` command in the project.
4. After that, I re-build the app using `react-native run-android`.
5. And Tada! the app is re-built without any error.